# How can I find a specific deleted question?

Tags: support

I can read some deleted questions, e.g. [Why the name Shepard?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1924/why-the-name-shepard) but I don't know how to find a specific one.

Is there a way of searching deleted questions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There isn't a way to search for deleted questions, except for diamond moderators. [A request for the ability](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41130/can-we-have-an-isdeleted1-search-option-operator) was marked [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) unceremoniously and without comment on [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com).

A quick search there for discussion about making deleted questions more visible leads to [a post by Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted/53297#53297) that indicates the lack of an easy way to find deleted questions is because questions are deleted for a reason, and it's not the goal to make them easier to be undeleted:

> Generally when things get deleted, it's for a good reason, and we don't want users to be undeleting them -- there's a reason we require 10k rep to "see" deleted items at all, and only moderators can see deletions in a user's profile.

And in response to a comment clarifying it's not about making it easier to undelete questions:

> it would lead to unbelievable amounts of whining. Will not get implemented as long as I am still alive to prevent it from happening.

Answer (score 2):

Users with at least 2000 reputation (10k after the site leaves beta) can see deleted posts. Only ♦ moderators can search deleted questions, or view them in user profiles. [Mark Trapp's answer](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/680/how-can-i-find-a-specific-deleted-question/681#681) explains why.

You can often find a deleted question by searching on Google. You're likely to find at least a link to the question, if not the question itself.

For those questions that were closed as part of the “culling of list questions”, the list is still visible in [this question's history](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/411/4).